# Sqlalchemy get integer from text query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am fighting with some legacy code and the correct way to get an integer value from the database. I am trying to get it like this:

```
db = make_session() # this returns a session
q = db.query('count').from_statement(text("""
    SELECT count(1) as count FROM mytable
    WHERE somevar=:somevar;
""")).params(somevar=1)
return [p[0] for p in q]
```

This returns `[81L]`. I would also think that the value is `q[0]` but that raises and Exception. What is the correct way to use Sqlalchemy in this case and get only an integer here.

Comment: Possibly `q.one().count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you'd want [`.scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar). For example, something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
db.query(func.count(mytable.id).filter(mytable.somevar == 1)).scalar()
```